# Geometry book for the mathematics GRE exam

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

Can someone recommend a geometry textbook for the mathematics GRE?

I'm not looking for a textbook that can be used to teach an undergraduate level course in geometry. Rather, I'm looking for a textbook that briefly covers the main results in Euclidean Geometry, and also perhaps includes material on analytic geometry (triangles inscribed in conic sections etc.). Also, I'm looking for a book which one can review in a few days. The book should also include some questions.

Comment: Any elementary geometry text does the trick.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Any suggestions? Most pre-calculus textbooks books seem to present the material with a focus on trigonometry and most undergraduate level books seem to well beyond the required material.